# Android - Custom GridView with separated XML

Tags: android, layout, gridview, customization

My goal is to display a chessboard. I have an Activity which displays a menu and load an instance of "ChessView" which extends GridView. I've created a custom GridView because I want to have a class fully dedicated to its display. So that class have its own layout.xml etc ...

GameActivity.java :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);


        //init a game
        CChess.getInstance().init();

        //creating the chessboard
        ChessView lChessView = (ChessView) findViewById(R.id.chessView);

    }
```

activity_game.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    tools:context=".GameActivity" >

    <project.chess.view.ChessView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ChessView"       >
    </project.chess.view.ChessView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ChessView.java :

```
public class ChessView extends GridView {

    public ChessView(Context pContext, AttributeSet pAttrs) {
        super(pContext, pAttrs);

        GridView.inflate(pContext, R.layout.view_chess, null);

        this.setAdapter(new ChessAdapter(pContext));
    }
}
```

view_chess.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"     >

    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:numColumns="8" 
        android:gravity="center" 
         >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

ChessAdapter.java :

```
public class ChessAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context mContext;

    public ChessAdapter (Context pContext)
    {
        this.mContext = pContext;   
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
        {
            return 64;
        }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView lImageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  
            lImageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            int size = parent.getWidth()/8;
            lImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(size,size));

        //background black or white depending of the position
        int col = position/8 %2;
        if (col == 0)
        {
            if (position%2 == 0)
                lImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            else
                lImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        else
        {
            if (position%2 == 0)
                lImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            else
                lImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        //load images
        CPiece p = CChess.getInstance().getPiece(position/8, position%8);


        if( p != null)
            lImageView.setImageResource(mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(p.toString(), "drawable", mContext.getPackageName()));
    } else {
        lImageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }


    return lImageView;
    }
   }
```

The result is : i have just 1 column of 64 squares all with an image (my init() in CChess is ok). To be clear, i want a 8x8 grid like all standards chessboards.

Few days ago, i had all this stuff in one activity without my custom view but just a simple gridView and all was working correctly. I have broken it since i've decided to separate my code in different classes

I'm sure i forgot something like an inflater somewhere but i don't understand how it works and what it does. I've parsed google for hours but i couldn't find the answer.

Can you help me please ? Thanks a lot for reading me and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think the problem with this LayoutInflator in ChessView.java

remove this line from that class

No Need to Inflate the GridView in that class

```
 GridView.inflate(pContext, R.layout.view_chess, null);
```

and set the Column count and gravity in Chess View in activity_game.xml file.

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:numColumns="8"
```

I Think this works for you.

Comment: Thank you ! It works now. Is there a way for the activity_game.xml to not having to set the number of column ? I mean, i think this is ChessView job or view_chess.xml job to do this, not their "parent". It would be great that all i need to do is to call ChessView without any other parameters in my activity to have my chessboard. Don't know if i am clear

Comment: In Chess View you can mention SetColumnCount(8) it works then you dont want to mention it in activity_game.xml file. Here view_chess.xml file is not required.

Comment: Perfect ! Exactly what i wanted. Thank you so much ! I'm wondering something : my view_chess.xml is useless now, but if i wanted to add some static configurations in there, how could i link it to my ChessView.java ? I'm just curious